# website lag due to sending email using google apps smtp

Tags: php, smtp, google-apps

I send email using the google apps smtp login from within by yii app. that works fine. the problem is that it creates a few seconds lag between pressing the submit and getting a response page. How can I create a proxy smtp on my ubuntu which picks up the mail as localhost  (instantly) and on separate thread sends in using google smtp without blocking by php thread.

Answer (score 0):

I would implement a sort of relay dilivery. Store email details somewhere (database or file) mark it as pending delivery and give the user immidiate response to avoid delay you're talking about. Then I probably design some php script that runs with cron (e.g. each minute) and delivers all pending messages.